# I meet a problem when I use websocket in my vue project

Tags: vue.js, websocket

Wrong when using websocket, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"

[image]

My code is :

```
    init() {
                let socket = new SockJS('http://127.0.0.1:8080/gs-guide-websocket');
                this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
                this.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
                    this.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg.body)
                    });
                });
            },
```